# Каскадное создание блоков через ajax

Tags: javascript

У меня есть `<select>`, по клику на который заполняется другой селект, который в свою очередь будет делать то же, что и предыдущий. Для того чтобы отследить событие клика на тот или иной селект требуется в цикле определится на какой же `<option>` мы кликаем, взяв его класс.

Для 1-го селекта:

```
 function choseCat(e){        
            вызов ajax для подгрузки значений из бд   
            формирует и создает option со своим классом 


        }    
            for (var i=0; i < cat_mass.length; i++) actionObj.addEvent(cat_mass[i], 'click', choseCat);
```

Для 2-го селекта:

```
function choseCat2(e){        
                вызов ajax для подгрузки значений из бд  
                формирует и создает второй option со своим классом    
            }    
                for (var i=0; i < cat_mass.length; i++) actionObj.addEvent(cat_mass2[i], 'click', choseCat2);
```

Для второго, казалось бы нужно делать абсолютно те же вещи, но когда я пытаюсь создать цикл и повесить на функцию клика какое-то действие, то ничего не происходит. Т.к первая функция отвечает за создание `<option>`, пробовал через консоль вывести результат создание этих `option`. И оказалось внутри ajax функции консоль выдает что они есть, а за пределами функции ajax я получаю в результате `[]`, хоть в этом не понятном массиве и хранятся те option-ы, которые мне нужны.
 
Почему так происходит? и как с этим бороться?

Первая мысль была - а почему бы не сделать ajax функцию внутри другой ajax функции, но я не думаю, что это правильный подход.

Comment: добавьте _рабочий_ вариант того, что вы делаете. Тут в сниппете, либо на jsfiddle. Иначе непонятно, что именно вы делаете и какие технологии и библиотеки используете.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») **должны включать** желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: В моем случае объект создает невидимый option, который должен сам поместить себя в дерево документа и ждать вызова остальных методов и свойств. Но в данном случае все методы объявлены в анонимной самовызывающейся ф-и

Comment: я специально выделил слова _должны включать минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе_ в предыдущем комментарии.

Comment: куда меньше сократить я уже не знаю, в любом случае версия будет не рабочей из за отсутствия бд, https://jsfiddle.net/sgfxc8wv/1/

Comment: не вижу ни одного `<select>`, база не нужна, можно просто эмулировать запрос, главное знать что он должен вернуть, кроме того при запуске ошибка: `Uncaught ReferenceError: cat_mass is not defined`

Comment: а также, что за `class="cat_%cat_id%"` и подобные плейсхолдеры? для примера они не нужны, нужна просто обычная разметка html

Comment: во всё, что стоит между `%%` попадают значения из бд. И в каждый спрятанный блок `hidden` попадают спаны (по тиму селекта и опций)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36504/discussion-between-grundy-and-dirk).